# How do I create a function to initialize a struct object in C++?

Tags: c++, public

Here is my code so far. ELEMENT is a class object that so far isn't giving me any trouble:

```
struct HEAP {
    public:
         int size;
         static int capacity;
         ELEMENT H[capacity];
         HEAP Initialize(int capacity);
}

HEAP HEAP::Initialize(int capacity) {
     ELEMENT * myHeap;
     myHeap = new ELEMENT [capacity];
}

int n;
n = 3;
Initialize(n);
```

I am new to C++ so I think I am unclear with how I am supposed to use class functions. Basically what I am trying to do is to initialize an array of pointers to element objects, and call that a heap. How am I using C++ functions incorrectly here? I'm used to Java so this feels a bit foreign to me.

Comment: This code is setup all wrong. `Initialize()` should be changed into a proper constructor, `H` needs to be changed to a pointer instead of a fixed array and then `myHeap` assigned to it, and you need to declare a `HEAP` object to construct/initialize in the first place. I suggest you get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) to learn from.

Comment: Why `Initialize`?  Why not constructor?

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback! I appreciate it.